# nginx server rewrite configuration

Tags: nginx

I have ngnix configured to load balance four tomcat applications.  I have a question about the rewrite/redirect rules for my server configuration section.

How do I make requests for http://zavlb.rand.int.co1 go to http://zavlb.rand.int.co1/zi/za/fpages/aaa/FPAGE_AAA_00_00.xhtml?

```
    upstream zavlb {
        ip_hash;
    #   server applnx1.za.rand.int.co1:8080 weight=2;
        server applnx01.za.rand.int.co1:8080 weight=2;
        server applnx02.za.rand.int.co1:8080 weight=2;
        server applnx03.za.rand.int.co1:8080 weight=2;
        server applnx04.za.rand.int.co1:8080 weight=2;
    }


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  zavlb.rand.int.co1;
        client_max_body_size 5m;

        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://zavlb;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        # redirect server error pages to the static page 404/index.html
        #
        error_page   404 500 502 503 504  404/index.html;
        location = 404/index.html {
            root   /home/za/www;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if i did not understood this correctly, but it seems to be you a URL redirect? In that case, you can use nginx rewrite module as described here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite. Ex:

```
rewrite / http://zavlb.rand.int.co1/zi/za/fpages/aaa/FPAGE_AAA_00_00.xhtml last;
```

However, if you want to serve that file from the backend server (proxy) when requests are hitting your root, you can use [nginx try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files), like:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.xhtml /zi/za/fpages/aaa/FPAGE_AAA_00_00.xhtml =404;
}
```

Hope this helps.